# How do I do a custom sort for a store in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I currently have the code below that overrides the sort for all stores.  What I need to do is create a sort for an individual store.  How do I do that?

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.Store, {
    // override
    createSortFunction: function (field, direction) {
        direction = direction || "ASC";
        var directionModifier = direction.toUpperCase() == "DESC" ? -1 : 1;
        var sortType = this.fields.get(field).sortType;

        //create a comparison function. Takes 2 records, returns 1 if record 1 is greater,
        //-1 if record 2 is greater or 0 if they are equal
        return function (r1, r2) {

            var v1;
            var v2;

            if (field == 'Registered') {
                v1 = sortType(r1.data['AircraftNeedsRegistered']);
                v2 = sortType(r2.data['AircraftNeedsRegistered']);

                if (r1.data['AircraftNeedsRegistered'])
                    r1.data['Register'] = !r1.data['Register'];

                if (r2.data['AircraftNeedsRegistered'])
                    r2.data['Register'] = !r2.data['Register'];

                //store.getAt(rowIndex).data['Registered'] = true;
            }
            else {
                v1 = sortType(r1.data[field]);
                v2 = sortType(r2.data[field]);
            }

            // To perform case insensitive sort
            if (v1.toLowerCase) {
                v1 = v1.toLowerCase();
                v2 = v2.toLowerCase();
            }

            return directionModifier * (v1 > v2 ? 1 : (v1 < v2 ? -1 : 0));
        };
    }
```

What I want to implement is something like this:

```
function AircraftStore() {
return new Ext.data.JsonStore(Ext.apply({
    url: AVRMS.ROOT_CONTEXT + "/ssl/json/general/GetAircraftByOwnerId.aspx",
    idProperty: 'OwnerOid',
    baseParams: { OwnerOid: 0 },
    fields: ['AircraftOid', 'NNumber', 'Make', 'Model', 'Seats', 'RegistrationType', 'Airworthy', 'IsFaaAirport', 'AirworthyString', 'IsFaaAirportString', 'Airport', 'AircraftNeedsRegistered', 'Register'],
    sort: function (field, direction) {
        return customSort(field, direction);
    }
}));
    };

function customSort(field,direction) {
    //What do I put here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the purpose of your code correctly but I believe the same effect can be achieved by using the following code (sorry, I haven't tested it but it should work).

```
AircraftStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.JsonStore, {
    url: AVRMS.ROOT_CONTEXT + "/ssl/json/general/GetAircraftByOwnerId.aspx",
    idProperty: 'OwnerOid',
    baseParams: { 
        OwnerOid: 0 
    },
    fields: ['AircraftOid', 'NNumber', 'Make', 'Model', 'Seats', 'RegistrationType', 'Airworthy', 'IsFaaAirport', 'AirworthyString', 'IsFaaAirportString', 'Airport', 'AircraftNeedsRegistered', 'Register'],
    sort: function (field, direction) {
        if (field == 'Registered') {
            field = 'AircraftNeedsRegistered';
            this.query('AircraftNeedsRegistered', true).each(function(record) {
                record.data['Register'] = !record.data['Register'];
            });         
        }
        return AircraftStore.superclass.sort.call(this, field, direction);
    }
});
```

If this does not achieve your desired behaviour because I missed something, you can just override the `createSortFunction` instead of `sort`. However, since `createSortFunction` is supposed to be private, it is better to handle custom logic by overriding `sort`. Anyway, if you prefer to stay with your first approach, your AircraftStore should look like this:

```
AircraftStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.JsonStore, {
    url: AVRMS.ROOT_CONTEXT + "/ssl/json/general/GetAircraftByOwnerId.aspx",
    idProperty: 'OwnerOid',
    baseParams: { 
        OwnerOid: 0 
    },
    fields: ['AircraftOid', 'NNumber', 'Make', 'Model', 'Seats', 'RegistrationType', 'Airworthy', 'IsFaaAirport', 'AirworthyString', 'IsFaaAirportString', 'Airport', 'AircraftNeedsRegistered', 'Register'],
    createSortFunction: function (field, direction) {
        // copy your createSortFunction here
    };
});
```